# Update PowerPoint slide with controls built on server

Tags: office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

I have an issue when trying to update a PowerPoint slide, more exactly I want to build on the server the controls that are not available on the frontend version of PowerPoint and then insert them into the slide.

Is there any way of doing this without inserting a new slide which is base64 encoded?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

May I ask what you mean by "controls built on server", can you specify your scenario a little bit?

For general updating the content of a slide, not shape or hyperlink specific, inserting a new slide with APU is the approach for now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).